# Automatically reference to a cell on other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I have a libre calc file with many sheets and I want the first sheet to contain a list with the other sheets names and next to each one the contents of a specific shell of every one of those sheets.
e.g. A1="sheet 2", B1=sheet2.C3, C1=sheet2.K3
A2= "sheet 3", B2=sheet3.C3, C2=sheet3.K3

The problem is i want that to happen automatically, i.e. to manually type the first row and drag down, so that the other ones get populated automatically.

Is that even possible, HOW???

Comment: List of sheet names = VBA unless the names follow a sequence like "Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", etc. Pulling a certain cell from each sheet once you have the list = `INDIRECT()` function. The formula for `B1` would be `=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!C3")`

Comment: thanks for your reply, maybe you could elaborate, what do you mean by VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how did you get C3, K3, I created a sample and entered the formula in ***Sheet1!A2***:

```
=INDIRECT(A$1&"!"&$D1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to solve the problem for me. I just want to point out for everyone else that the cell name must not contain any spaces.

Another thing i want to ask is if there is a way to automaticaly list the sheet names on column A?

Comment: To reference sheet names with spaces in it, you need to wrap the sheet name in single quotes: `=INDIRECT("'"&A$1&"'!"&$D1)`

Comment: thanks a lot, that helped